# ASP.NET MVC 3 new project template - modernizr not working with IE8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modernizr

I like the new New Project templates included in the ASP.NET MVC3 tools update, as presented at MIX 11 recently.

A basic site can be seen here:
http://mix11.haacked.com/

When I view the above site in Chrome, the HTML5 styles are visible - rounded corners and text shadow.
[image: chrome]

When I view the site in IE8 those styles aren't visible.
[image: ie8]

My question is, isn't Modernizr supposed to make these styles work in older browsers?

-Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modernizer won't actually add missing functionality to a browser. Basically, you use it as a guide to tell you whether a browser supports a certain feature. In your case, you could have a CSS file which will compensate for browsers that don't support border radius:

```
.no-borderradius div {
  /* properties for browsers that don't support border-radius */
}
```

The above is a total made-up example, I'm not sure 100% if it's correct, but check the documentation [here](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#borderradius).

So for IE8, you would need to display rounded corners using a different technique.